# Como puedo hacer para manipular la accion del boton de SweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Necesito que cuando yo apriete el boton de confirmar en la alerta me rediriga a una pagina que yo quiero, para ser mas especifico, es a la pagina de Whatsapp para enviar un mensaje con un cuerpo de texto. El problema es que no encuentro la forma de hacer que al tocar el boton "OK" se abra esta pagina, ya hice varios intentos pero siempre se abre apenas me sale la alerta. Tambien cabe destacar que la alerta dentro tiene un input.

const alerta=()=>{

```
  var domicilio = "a"
  var url = "s"

  swal.fire({
    title: 'Ultimo Paso! Datos de Envío',
    input: 'text',
    inputLabel: 'Domicilio',
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      console.log(value)
      const domicilio = value
      if (!value) {
        return 'No ingresaste ningun Domicilio!'
      }
    }
 })  

 console.log(domicilio)

 for(let item of cartItems) {
  console.log(item)

  let acumulador = " " + item.amount + " Porciones de " + item.name

  var texto = texto + ", " + acumulador

  let url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${3534222573}&text=
            Hola,%20quisiera%20hacer%20%un%20%pedido: ${texto} + ${domicilio}`
 }         
return window.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise el código porque posiblemente tenga errores por variables null o undefined, pero lo que quiere hacer puede ser algo como esto: Evidentemente no va a conectar el API de whatsapp desde aquí, eso ya tiene que hacerlo inclusive no se si con un proxy para poder probarlo, no estoy seguro sino tiene que publicar la web y probar cuando este publicada, eso ya le toca averiguarlo con el api de whatsapp

```js
var whatsapp=document.querySelector('#whatsapp')
whatsapp.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
e.preventDefault()
    var url

  const alert= swal.fire({
      title: 'Ultimo Paso! Datos de Envío',
      input: 'text',
      inputLabel: 'Domicilio',
      showCancelButton: true
   }).then((result)=>{
        //validar nul, undefined, etc
        if(result!==typeof(null)){
          let texto="No se que va aquí"
           url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?  phone=${3534222573}&text=
                    Hola,%20quisiera%20hacer%20%un%20%pedido:       ${texto} + ${result}`        
        location.href=url
        }
   })
  
})
```

```html
<html>
<H1>SwetAlert</H1>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<button id="whatsapp">Enviar whatsapp</button>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! me funciono